# Setting 0 pixel value to novalue using GDAL in Pythin API

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdal-translate

I have a raster data and i want to set the 0 value pixels to NoData using GDAL in python API.

I know that you can do this by inputting this code in the command prompt.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 input.tif output.tif
```

but can anyone translate this so that i can put it in a Python API?

Comment: A bit unclear what you mean, but you can `gdal.Translate("output.tif", "input.tif", format="GTiff", noData=0)` is equivalent to your command.

Comment: Hello @Jose. Thanks for this, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use gdal_edit.py script https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html or study the code and re-use in your own script.

```
-a_nodata <value>
Assign a specified nodata value to output bands.
```

Gdal_translate creates a new copy from your tif while gdal_edit updates just the GeoTIFF metadata in-place.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this, this may be a better alternative to gdal.translate. May I ask how to do this code in a python API? Im sorry, im terrible in translating code from command line to python api. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with rasterio (GDAL python wrapper) using `r+` mode:

```py
import rasterio

with rasterio.open(file, 'r+') as rds:
    rds.nodata = 0
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this. Will try it out.